# Check for two dataframes (pivot tables) similarity

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to check the percent of similarity between two pandas pivot tables (which are filled with values 1 and Nan) which have same row and column indices. I want to count the number of the same rows and divide them by the total number of rows.
Giving basic example:

```
df1

       column1    column2    column3
 idx1   Nan        1           Nan
 idx2   1          Nan         1
 idx3   Nan        Nan         1

df1

       column1    column2    column3
 idx1   1          Nan         1
 idx2   1          Nan         1
 idx3   Nan        1           1
```

In this basic example, the only row with idx2 has the same value in both data frames, so the output would be 1/3 ~ 33%

I tried inner join (to check overlapping) but I got some error 'key error 0'
Another attempt was with c = a[!a.isin(b)], but I got some weird values..

Comment: Does `Nan` represent the missing value (np.nan)? And in your case `NaN==Nan` is valid? Also do `idx2` duplicate intentionally?

Comment: Yes, Nan is missing value (I can replace it with -1 for example, it's important)
Yeah, that was mistake :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becasue same index and columns values you can first replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if all `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), last for percentage use `mean` (`True/False`s are processing like `1/0`):

```
out = df1.fillna('missing').eq(df2.fillna('missing')).all(axis=1).mean() * 100
print (out)
33.33333333333333
```

Comment: @sophocles - Yop, NaN != NaN, so simpliest is replace it.

Comment: Yes exactly. And good spot adding ```axis=1``` in ```all``` :)

Comment: I also tried something similar, but didn't know that I need to fillnan.  Thank you jezrael!